# ¿Cómo puedo loguearme con requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy intentando loguear en esta [web](https://www.dofus.com/es) con la librería **requests**, pero no loguea de ninguna manera, si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería.

He estado mirando tutoriales en los que decían que hacía falta un "csrf_token" o "authentication_token" pero no veo nada de eso al depurar en la ventana "Networks" del navegador

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


username = "user"
password = "pass"

landing_page = "https://www.dofus.com/es/identificacion"
login_page = "https://account.ankama.com/sso?from=https://www.dofus.com/es/identificacion"

br = Session()

header = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "es-ES,es;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 OPR/62.0.3331.132"
}

form_data = {
    "login": username,
    "password": password
}

br.headers.update(header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.get(landing_page))

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 3):

Si haces un login desde tu navegador y abres las pestaña Network del depurador del navegador veras que usan el captcha de google

```
action: login
from: https://www.dofus.com/es
login: aaa
password: bbb
remember: 1
g-recaptcha-response: 03AOLTBLSd9kJVIv3PtCi1NIIWdqKYEpczPxTnyv4SGT_NyraYxpPMaORp3dPt4l1kh3s3P1JuMc4zdLap5P9nYfnjeUp_nu67iF0LmD266o2-IlHnF8am18xQrvxY7P4fOnuuypZcCu-XATWpXwocDpkJXw7NflDlK61x3AWDz8K3LzhmKhZZo6f2d9yVYOag4QF2e5plpNi6c_EUIKJ3bQ9Fihb21y8LH7qA6z-ikoAcRnGN_CHcjM-sI0yH8s2iGeHMnJkWUpls-YVsbfJuhhBPzXsz35qAmnJqL1jbBqPEw118v1KxH4nOBjqeMqxvUP6OZEC8JPMBHUUJnB4UvS7V17u3t3KnZw
```

Comment: Si, correcto, pero de donde saco el token para mandarlo con mi header?

Comment: No puedes, ese captcha esta para evitar lo que tu estas intentando hacer